# How to Auto-Increment a big int in Pervasive

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

Using the [graphical table editor](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/index.html#page/uguide%2FnewTableWizard.htm%23ww106704), in Pervasive 13, how can I set a **big int** as a unique auto-incrementing id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/#page/whnew%2Fwhatsnew.htm%23ww539373) for ZEN (PSQL) v13, it says:

> Btrieve
>   In Btrieve operations, the length of the AUTOINC data type can
>   now be 8 bytes as well as 2 or 4 bytes. The new length is available in
>   files using 9.5 format and later. Btrieve files using the new 8-byte
>   AUTOINC segment cannot be opened by engines from earlier releases.

It appears that the 8 byte integer is not available from the SQL side of the Zen (PSQL) engine and is only available from the Btrieve API.

You *might* be able to create the file with the 8 byte autoincrement and then create a SQL definition for the table but I'm not sure.   You can't do it from the graphical table editor.

Answer (score 1):

The column type can be set to `AUTOINC(8)` to specify an auto-incrementing 8-byte sequence number.

http://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html#page/sqlref/sqldtype.htm

Comment: Would it let you select `IDENTITY` and then enter 8 as the size of the column?

Comment: I can select IDENTITY, but it doesn't allow me to input a size.